# Spring + Hibernate + DAO + SessionFactory + Inject

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

I use Spring with Hibernate and get always a NPE for the sessionFactory Object.

My config file:

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfiguration {

@Bean
public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("hibernate.dialect", MySQL5InnoDBDialect.class.getName());
    props.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    props.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    props.put("hibernate.connection.password", "xxx");
    props.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Market");
    props.put("hibernate.connection.username", "philipp");

    AnnotationSessionFactoryBean bean = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
    bean.setAnnotatedClasses(new Class[] { xxx.class, xxx.class, xxx.class });
    bean.setHibernateProperties(props);
    bean.setSchemaUpdate(true);
    return bean;
}





@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory().getObject());
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}
```

}

My DAOImpl class:

```
@Repository("xxx")
public class xxxDAOImpl implements xxxDAO {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

private Session currentSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
...
```

Testcase:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestxxxDAOImpl {

@Test
@Transactional
public void testInsertxxx() throws Exception {

    xxxDAO xxxDAO = new xxxDAOImpl();
    xyz xyz = new xyz();
    xxxDAO.insert(xyz);
    assertNotNull(xyz.getId());
    }
```

}

app-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"   xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.config" />
<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.dao" />
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
```

test-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml" />
```

I get always an NPE from the currentSession when the test calls the insert method.

```
public void insert(xxx xxx) {
    currentSession().save(xxx);
}


private Session currentSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing to understand when working with Spring is that Spring dependency injection only works for beans obtained from the application context, not for beans created with `new`.

In Spring-enabled unit tests you configure application context using `@ContextConfiguration`, for example, as follows (works in Spring 3.1, in previous versions `@ContextConfiguration` doesn't take `@Configuration` classes directly, therefore you'll have to create XML configuration file):

```
@Configuration 
public class HibernateConfiguration { 
    // Add your DAO to application context
    @Bean
    public xxxDAO xxxDAO() {
        return new xxxDAOImpl();
    }
    ...
}

// Configure application context using the given @Configuration class
@ContextConfiguration(classes = HibernateConfiguration.class)   
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestxxxDAOImpl {
    // Obtain DAO from the application context    
    @Autowired xxxDao xxxDao;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This wont work with more than one configuration. Autowired takes no name.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() in currentSession() function of xxxDAOImpl class, use sessionFactory.openSession().

Since in your first call there would not be any current session in the session factory so you need to open the session.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: The sessionFactory should be injected and so I have always a session in my xxxDAOImpl class. The problem is that's the sessionFactory is not injected by Spring.

Comment: I recommend you check the NPE point once again properly. I suspect the problem is in getCurrentSession as I have said. Please show your stack trace here so that I can undestand well.